# How to get a control or a box created in memory but not render it on a page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a solution where I need to make certain calculations on a label with certain text in it. However, I don't want to render that label on the page. Once, the calculations are made, the label can be discarded.

Is it possible in JavaScript to create such a label in the memory for calculations and not render it on the page?
I don't want to render even a hidden control, as even that would need some space and modification on the web page.

Comment: Yes, you can base calculations on a label in an html document in javascript and you don't have to show the result of the calculation anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Dov. What you said makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

---

You will need to append the element to the DOM if you want to do calculations based on the rendered size of the element. Here's a way to do that without affecting the layout of your page:

```
const hiddenLabel = document.createElement("span");

hiddenLabel.innerHTML = "Some Text";

Object.assign(hiddenLabel.style, {
  position: "absolute", // removes element from document flow
  visibility: "hidden", // element invisible, but layout still computed
});

document.body.appendChild(hiddenLabel);

// inspect dimensions of the rendered element.
console.log(hiddenLabel.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

This particular example might be useful if, for example, you're trying to resize an input field based on the length of the input.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. This is pretty close to what I am looking for.